# Neo4J - Spring Boot - Spring Security - Java Config

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

Where can someone find an example of users and authorites (roles) stored in a Neo4J DB other than Cineasts that is using old versions of Spring Data Neo4J (SDN). I would prefer it if its only Java Config (no xml) and is using the latest versions of Spring Boot - Spring Security and SDN. Google search does not bring up anything. It will be of great help if someone creates a seed app for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/pvlastaridis/Neo4JHipster

At last I ve made it. A full authenticated rest app with Neo4J spring-boot and spring-data-neo4j. It is based on fantastic yo generator JHIPSTER. Thank you jhipster. Looking forward for the next update of Spring Data Neo4J so we can have it on a remote Neo4J server.